# Quote a filename containing quotes and given as variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, macos, command-line

Let's say I have a directory path in variable `DIR` and I want to list this directory. If I care only about spaces in the path, then I could do

```
ls "$DIR"
```

What should I write if I want to support also single and double quotes and other weird stuff in the directory path? Example:

```
DIR="/Users/Mick O'Neil (the \"Terminator\")/Desktop"
echo $DIR # prints /Users/Mick O'Neil (the "Terminator")/Desktop
ls <what should I write here?>
```

Comment: [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/608639), [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/608639), [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/56041), [How to handle spaces in filenames using double quotes in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32767951/608639), [Listing files in date order with spaces in filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4583801/608639), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quotes are not just for spaces but for everything, so using the double quotes is the safety level you need here.

From [Bash Reference Manual on Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes):

> 3.1.2.3 Double Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’.

---

Let's store this string into a file for later usage.

```
$ cat file
Mick O'Neil (the "Terminator")
```

Read into a var:

```
$ filename=$(<file)
```

Check its value:

```
$ echo "$filename"
Mick O'Neil (the "Terminator")
```

Create a file with this value:

```
$ touch "$filename"
```

Check it has been created successfully:

```
$ lt "$filename"
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 0 Mar  1 15:09 Mick O'Neil (the "Terminator")
```

Comment: Whoa, so it was a non-issue :) 
Thanks!