# No such file error while file output redirection

Tags: linux, bash

Iam trying to append date to a file that iam creating but it results in no such file or directory found error. If i remove the date from the below code it works fine.

`fileName="other.txt."$(date "+%D %T")
echo "hello" >>  $fileName`

Comment: You are crafting a file name with a space in it, plus, with some locales, slashes. This is not a very reasonable choice. Prefer a more predictable, and shell-friendly name, like `fileName=$(date +"other.txt.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S")`, for instance.

Comment: [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/608639), [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/56041), [How to handle spaces in filenames using double quotes in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32767951/608639), [Listing files in date order with spaces in filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4583801/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
filename=blah.txt.`date "+%D%T"`
```

output:

```
$ echo $filename
blah.txt.08/29/1808:05:01
```

I would suggest changing the format to something without slashes like:

```
filename=blah.txt.`date "+%d%m%y%T"`
```